# How to write an exception that does not require try/catch?

Tags: java, exception

Is it even possible?

From what I read in the Java Tutorial, methods that throw `RuntimeException` do not need to be surrounded by `try`/`catch` nor throw. Is it possible to write my own `RuntimeException`?

Comment: I don't understand this question.  Since when could you surround any method by try, catch, or throw?

Comment: I believe he is referring to surrounding calls to a method with try/catch when they can throw a checked exception.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {

     /* add constructors. */

}
```